# Laravel adding an alert to a view

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, view, alert

I am trying to add an alert/warning to a view but displaying nothing.  I can get my alerts to work with a redirect but wondering how to do it with a view that passes data.  Is there a way to pass an alert to a view or is there a "Correct" way of doing this?

```
$form = new Form();
$form->storeRequest($request);
$form->saveJson();
$form->loadForm($request->cuid, $request->cubaseName);
return view('layouts.pages.form', ['form'=>$form])->with('success', 'Form has been saved.');
//return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Saved!'); <--this would work if i wasn't passing data
```

Comment: "I am trying to add an alert/warning to a view but displaying nothing.". Can you post a snippet of what your blade view is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Framework use a special method to send message from controller known as `Flash message`

In your controller

```
$request->session()->flash('success', 'Form has been saved');
```

And to access it on view

```
 @if($message = Session::get("success"))
      <h3 class="text-center text-success">{{$message}}</h3>
 @endif
```

[Laravel -> Http Session -> Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#flash-data)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a neat way of doing something like bootstrap alerts, you should consider the `laracasts/flash` package by Jeffrey Way.

Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)